Destroy method of a Container is not called at the end of a test class execution
I have embedded containers for tests, Kafka, Postree, Minio, etc.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.playtika.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.playtika.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.playtika.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-mssqlserver</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.playtika.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-minio</artifactId>
</dependency>

I use a custom annotation EnableTestContainers, which raises the containers I need for the test class.
But I noticed that after the tests are completed, the containers in Docker do not complete their work, but hang until all test classes are completed.
I tried adding the setting embedded.containers.force-shutdown=true, but apparently doesn't work because of the spring context, and only shuts down containers after all tests have been run
I tried adding @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS).
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS) works well for closing containers after class execution, but breaks the logic of @Nested tests
Is a problem for my tests, because there are many already written tests via @Nested classes, and they use the parent context for their tests.
Two questions:
How can I close containers after the class with tests is completed without DirtiesContext? (So ​​that it does not interfere with Nested tests)
Or, if the DirtiesContext annotation is still needed, then how can I make it so that it only works on the parent class, and does not clear the context after executing the Nested class?

What does your @EnableTestContainers annotation do? If they are tied to the lifecycle of the application context they will live as long as the context lives. Why do you need to shutdown the containers in the first place, feels like you are doing your tests wrong.

@m-deinum Suppose I will use the same PostgreSQL container everywhere, after each test I will need to clean the tables that were used in the previous test. Similarly with Kafka, after each test class I will need to clean all old messages and topics

Recreating container will be expensive, why dont write a clean up script in BeforeAll or AfterAll ?

Postgres with docker and testcontainers starts in less then a second, does it really take that much more time to cleanup the data afterwards? If you want to cleanup then truncate all tables in there (you could do that in a script or your own execution that happens).
